# JQuery - "Read More" slide animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a blog and added a plugin to truncate the text by height with a "Read More" button.

This is the javascript function:

```
(function ( $ ) {
$.fn.readMoreFade = function(options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        backgroundColor: "white",
        buttonClass: "button"
    }, options );

    this.css( "height", 325 );
    this.css( "overflow", "hidden" );
    this.css( "position", "relative" );
    this.append('<p class="readMoreFade"><a href="#" class="btn btn-red">Ler Mais</a></p>')

    var readMoreButton = this.find('.readMoreFade');
    var backgroundString = settings.backgroundColor ? settings.backgroundColor : this.css('background-color');

    readMoreButton.css('background-image', '-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, rgba(0,255,255,0)),color-stop(1, '+backgroundString+'))');
    readMoreButton.css('text-align', 'center');
    readMoreButton.click(function(){
            totalHeight = 0

            $el = $(this);
            $p  = $el;
            $up = $p.parent();
            $ps = $up.find("p:not('.readMoreFade'), ul:not('.readMoreFade'), ol:not('.readMoreFade'), img:not('.readMoreFade'), h2:not('.readMoreFade'), h3:not('.readMoreFade'), h4:not('.readMoreFade'), h5:not('.readMoreFade')");

            $ps.each(function() {
                totalHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
            });

            $up
                .animate({
                    "height": totalHeight
                });

            // fade out read-more
            $p.fadeOut();

            // prevent jump-down
            return false;
    })

    return this;
};
```

}( jQuery ));

But, the thing is: it is giving a lot of space after the text is finished.
I would like to know if there is a way to "delete" this blank space (yellow space in the image below)

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzOWL.png)

Comment: Please share your code so will give you proper solution.

Comment: These are well-solved problems with tons of prepackaged solutions readily available for a vast array of different platforms. Why are you trying to code this yourself?